# Scrapy: Custom Call-Backs do not work

Tags: python, callback, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm at a loss for why my spider doesn't work!  I am by **no** means a programmer so please be kind! haha

**Background:**
I'm trying to scrape the information pertaining to books found on Indigo with the use of "Scrapy".

**Problem:**
My code does not enter any of my custom call-backs... It seems to work only when I use "parse" as the call-back.

If I were to change the call-back in the "Rules" section of the code from "parse_books" to "parse", the method where I make a list of all of the links works just fine and prints out all of the links I'm interested in.  However, the call-back within that method (pointing to "parse_books") never gets called!  Oddly enough, if I were to rename the "parse" method to something else (i.e. -> "testmethod") and then rename the "parse_books" method to "parse", the method where I *scrape* information into items works just fine!

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
All I want to do is enter a page, let's say "best-sellers", navigate to the respective item-level pages for all of the items and scrape all of the book-related information.  I seem to have both both things working independently :/

The Code!

```
import scrapy
import json
import urllib
from scrapy.http import Request
from urllib import urlencode
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import urlparse



from TEST20160709.items import IndigoItem
from TEST20160709.items import SecondaryItem



item = IndigoItem()
scrapedItem = SecondaryItem()

class IndigoSpider(CrawlSpider):

    protocol='https://'
    name = "site"
    allowed_domains = [
    "chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/Books",
    "chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/Store/Availability/"
    ]

    start_urls = [
         'https://www.chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/books/bestsellers/',
    ]

    #extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor()s

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow = True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback = "parse_books", follow = True),
    )



    def getInventory (self, bookID):
        params ={
       'pid' : bookID,
       'catalog' : 'books'
        }
        yield Request(
            url="https://www.chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/Store/Availability/?" + urlencode(params),
            dont_filter = True,
            callback = self.parseInventory
        )



    def parseInventory(self,response):
        dataInventory = json.loads(response.body)

        for entry in dataInventory ['Data']:
            scrapedItem['storeID'] = entry['ID']
            scrapedItem['storeType'] = entry['StoreType']
            scrapedItem['storeName'] = entry['Name']
            scrapedItem['storeAddress'] = entry['Address']
            scrapedItem['storeCity'] = entry['City']
            scrapedItem['storePostalCode'] = entry['PostalCode']
            scrapedItem['storeProvince'] = entry['Province']
            scrapedItem['storePhone'] = entry['Phone']
            scrapedItem['storeQuantity'] = entry['QTY']
            scrapedItem['storeQuantityMessage'] = entry['QTYMsg']
            scrapedItem['storeHours'] = entry['StoreHours']
            scrapedItem['storeStockAvailibility'] = entry['HasRetailStock']
            scrapedItem['storeExclusivity'] = entry['InStoreExlusive']

            yield scrapedItem



    def parse (self, response):
        #GET ALL PAGE LINKS
        all_page_links = response.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        for relative_link in all_page_links:
            absolute_link = urlparse.urljoin(self.protocol+"www.chapters.indigo.ca",relative_link.strip())
            absolute_link = absolute_link.split("?ref=",1)[0]
            request = scrapy.Request(absolute_link, callback=self.parse_books)
            print "FULL link: "+absolute_link

            yield Request(absolute_link, callback=self.parse_books)





    def parse_books (self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//form[@id="aspnetForm"]/main[@id="main"]'):
            #XML/HTTP/CSS ITEMS
            item['title']= map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('div[@class="content-wrapper"]/div[@class="product-details"]/div[@class="col-2"]/section[@id="ProductDetails"][@class][@role][@aria-labelledby]/h1[@id="product-title"][@class][@data-auto-id]/text()').extract())
            item['authors']= map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('div[@class="content-wrapper"]/div[@class="product-details"]/div[@class="col-2"]/section[@id="ProductDetails"][@class][@role][@aria-labelledby]/h2[@class="major-contributor"]/a[contains(@class, "byLink")][@href]/text()').extract())
            item['productSpecs']= map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('div[@class="content-wrapper"]/div[@class="product-details"]/div[@class="col-2"]/section[@id="ProductDetails"][@class][@role][@aria-labelledby]/p[@class="product-specs"]/text()').extract())
            item['instoreAvailability']= map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('//span[@class="stockAvailable-mesg negative"][@data-auto-id]/text()').extract())
            item['onlinePrice']= map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('//span[@id][@class="nonmemberprice__specialprice"]/text()').extract())
            item['listPrice']= map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('//del/text()').extract())

            aboutBookTemp = map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('//div[@class="read-more"]/p/text()').extract())
            item['aboutBook']= [aboutBookTemp]

            #Retrieve ISBN Identifier and extract numeric data
            ISBN_parse = map(unicode.strip, sel.xpath('(//div[@class="isbn-info"]/p[2])[1]/text()').extract())
            item['ISBN13']= [elem[11:] for elem in ISBN_parse]
            bookIdentifier = str(item['ISBN13'])
            bookIdentifier = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", bookIdentifier)


            print "THIS IS THE IDENTIFIER:" + bookIdentifier

            if bookIdentifier:
                yield self.getInventory(str(bookIdentifier))

            yield item
```

Comment: Your methods seem out of the class. Can you please format the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first ploblems I've noticed is that your `allowed_domains` class attribute is broken. It should contain **domains** (thus the name).

Correct value in your case would be:

```
allowed_domains = [
    "chapters.indigo.ca",  # subdomain.domain.top_level_domain
]
```

If you check your spider log you would see:

```
DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.chapters.indigo.ca'
```

which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working! The "parseInventory" method doesn't seem to be triggered, but you have definitely saved the day.  I deeply appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the question if you found that it solves your issue :)